# How do I return a single element of a MongoDB array?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I would like to return a single element of a Mongodb array. I am taking a username and password from a form and using the `findOne()` function to verify it's existence in the database.

```
$user = $collection->findOne(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
 ));
```

In the array that it returns there is also a zip code. I would like to store that element of the array in a variable to concatenate it with another variable.

Comment: Doesn't `$zip_code = $user["zip_code_or_something"]` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$user = $collection->findOne(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
     ));

var_dump($user);  // you will see your document as a PHP associative array here 
$myPin = $user['pincode_keyname']; // or whatever name your pincode element has

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an to return all this information. As I understood all you need is a pincode, so your query should be this way

```
$user = $collection->findOne(
  array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
  ),
  array(
    'pincode'  => 1,
    '_id'      => 0
  )
)
```

;

$user['pincode'] will be a pincode you need.
the second array ensure that you will not receive any additional and unimportant information except of pincode